# Concatenating Multiple Cells into One using Python

Tags: python, pandas

My file is in CSV format with 4 data columns. I want all the four-cells under each column to be concatenated into one cell using python. After this, I want to transform CSV file to Unix file.

I've tried below but it didn't work.

```
data = data.stack().reset_index()
data.columns = ['Source','Description','Date','Values']
data['Date'] = [t.strftime('%Y%m%d') for t in data['Date']]
data['Source'] = 'AAAA'
data = data[['Source','MKF','Date','TS']]
```

Input from csv file:

```
AAAA    MendokoroRamen  20080102    5
AAAA    Ramenhouse  20080102    5.45
AAAA    RamenNagi   20080102    5.5
AAAA    RamenBowl   20080102    5.55
```

Expected Output:

```
AAAA,MendokoroRamen,20080102,5

AAAA,Ramenhouse,20080102,5.45

AAAA,RamenNagi,20080102,5.5

AAAA,RamenBowl,20080102,5.55
```

Also, I want this CSV file to be saved in Unix file or txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how I did it. Let me know if it works.

Input file: (`mycsv.csv`):

```
AAAA    MendokoroRamen  20080102    5
AAAA    Ramenhouse  20080102    5.45
AAAA    RamenNagi   20080102    5.5
AAAA    RamenBowl   20080102    5.55
```

python script:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv', header=None, sep='\s+', engine='python')
df.columns = ['Source','Description','Date','Values']
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')
df.to_csv('out.csv',index=False)
#df.to_csv('out.csv',index=False, header=False) #To remove headings
```

Explanation:

- Read csv with No header, use space separation then
- Add columns :  `'Source','Description','Date','Values'`
- Change the column  to   datetime
- Export to csv (`out.csv`)

Output:

```
Source,Description,Date,Values
AAAA,MendokoroRamen,2008-01-02,5.0
AAAA,Ramenhouse,2008-01-02,5.45
AAAA,RamenNagi,2008-01-02,5.5
AAAA,RamenBowl,2008-01-02,5.55
```

Answer (score 0):

I think pandas DataFrame.to_csv()-method is what you are looking for.

Try:

```py
data.to_csv(index=False)
```

And check out the pandas documentation regarding this topic:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

E.g. you could also define which delimiter you want to use but comma is default.